# Blazor Web Assembly - Difference between various OIDC Authentication Paths

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

While configuring **Blazor Web Assembly *Standalone***, we have to specify the Oidc options using an Identity provider. For this we can use AddOidcAuthentication.

Now for configuring the AddOidcAuthentication we have to configure ProviderOptions and AuthenticationPaths.

AuthenticationPaths are the authentication path options as described in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticationapplicationpathsoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[RemoteAuthenticationApplicationPathsOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticationapplicationpathsoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0) have LogInPath, ProfilePath, RegisterPath. My understanding is that these are the actual remote login, profile and register paths as described by your Identity Provider documentation and our Web assembly will be redirected to authenticate, registry or modify user.

**But I also see that there is an explicit RemoteProfilePath and RemoteRegisterPath.**

So here are my confusions !

1. What is the difference between ProfilePath and RemoteProfilePath and similarly difference between RegisterPath and RemoteRegisterPath?
2. When we are using an IdentityProvider I thought the paths will always be remote, as they are not native to you web assembly application and they are provided by your Identity Provider (like Microsoft, Google etc.). We would do an authentication for user against these paths for a client Id. Is this not correct ?
3. If there is difference between RegisterPath and RemoteRegisterPath, **then why there is no RemoteLoginPath.**
4. And finally when do use which version of authentication path, is there any example or documentation that explains this ?

I tried searching for documentation or example but could not fine a clear explanation. Any thought and explanations to help clarify this from experts is really appreciated !